# Flutter Methode Channels Objective C send and use UInt8List

Tags: ios, objective-c, dart, flutter

I tried writing my own flutter plugin, sending an UInt8List to native Android and IOS. Everything works fine on the Android part but the IOS part isn't working. Im trying to save a byte array as an image. I know there are libaries for something similar but that is not what i want :)

Inside my Methode Channel File, i call the following function:

```
   static Future<void> saveImage({
    @required String filename,
    @required Uint8List bytes
  }) async {
    assert(bytes != null && filename != null);

    final bool success = await _channel.invokeMethod(
      'saveImage',
      <String, dynamic>{
        'filename': filename,
        'bytes': bytes,
      },
    );

    return success;
  }
```

In my IOS Code i try to read the byte array and turn it into an image.

```
- (void)handleMethodCall:(FlutterMethodCall*)call result:(FlutterResult)result {
    if ([@"saveImage" isEqualToString:call.method]) {
        NSDictionary *_arguments = call.arguments;
        NSData *data = [_arguments objectForKey:@"bytes"];
        NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy: (__bridge void * _Nonnull)(data) length:sizeof(data) freeWhenDone:YES];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);
        result(FlutterMethodNotImplemented); // For Test purposes

    } else {
        result(FlutterMethodNotImplemented);
    }
}
```

But this throws an Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x20) during the closing else Bracket. I Get no other error. Some PO Commands showed the following informations:

```
(lldb) po _arguments
{
    bytes = "<FlutterStandardTypedData: 0x114dfb110>";
    filename = "1545043056295.jpeg";
}

(lldb) po data
<FlutterStandardTypedData: 0x114dfb110>

(lldb) po imageData
<1972c703 a1410000>

(lldb) po image
 nil
```

To me it seems that im not able to create the NSData image object from Bytearray but im not sure why. Can somebody help me out here ?